# Using UCWA API to schedule Lync meetings

Tags: c#, lync, ucwa

I have authenticated and authorized UCWA API in C#. Application id is also generated using generated token. When i tried to create lync meeting using following code I am getting error "Internal Server Error".
Error:-

```
{"code":"ServiceFailure","message":"Your request couldn't be completed.","debugInfo":{"errorReportId":"e2c35f5e0b274c4185d08837dd7e16a3"}}
```

My code is :-

```
onlinemeetingURL = "https://lynctswebint.Mycompany.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/101030060103/onlineMeetings/myOnlineMeetings";
    request = new RestRequest(onlinemeetingURL, Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Host", "lynctswebint.Mycompany.com");
    request.AddHeader("expirationTime","1482572914000");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", String.Format("{0} {1}", applicationTokenType, applicationToken));
    var applicationBody = @"""lobbyBypassForPhoneUsers"" : ""Disabled"",""phoneUserAdmission"" : ""Disabled"",""description"":""{0}"",""subject"":""{1}"",""attendees"":""{2}"",""leaders"":""{3}""";
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
    request.AddParameter(
        "application/json",
       "{" + string.Format(applicationBody, "This is a test for UCWA meeting creation", "Test UCWA meeting creation", "sip:testonline.lync@Mycompany.com", "sip:lync.test@Mycompany.com") + "}",
        ParameterType.RequestBody);
    ucwaClient.ExecuteAsync(request, this.functionToCall);
```

There are not more details about this error. I am using restSharp library for this.

Comment: Can you show what your request body looks like in a network trace or otherwise.  Is there a reason that request.RequestFormat is set as DataFormat.Xml when you are sending JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Other than what mentioned about inconsistent specification of payload's format, your code/payload contains few errors.

For instance, *expirationTime* information must be as well provided in the payload body, and not as part of request headers.
Also, *attendees* and *leaders* are expected to be arrays..

I suggest you to read and implement carefully what documented at
[myOnlineMeetings resource](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-myOnlineMeetings)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I corrected as per your suggestion and still getting same error. Going through your given link it seem error is related to nvalidExchangeServerVersion, I am using a service account with no mail box associated, this could be a reason for the error.

Comment: Thanks for the link shared. Issue resolved and i posted my correction. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet in my code was not correct.

```
request.AddParameter(
        "application/json",
       "{" + string.Format(applicationBody, "This is a test for UCWA meeting creation", "Test UCWA meeting creation", "sip:testonline.lync@Mycompany.com", "sip:lync.test@Mycompany.com") + "}",
        ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I had to pass the array for attendee and leaders whereas i was passing string.
I corrected it as follows and its working fine now.

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n \"attendanceAnnouncementsStatus\":\"Enabled\",\r\n \"description\":\"This is a test for UCWA meeting creation\",\r\n \"subject\":\"Test UCWA meeting creation\",\r\n \"attendees\": [\"sip:testonline.lync@mycompany.com\"],\r\n \"leaders\": [\"sip:lync.test@mycompany.com\"]\r\n }", ParameterType.RequestBody)
```